# How to store variables in class to be retrieved by another python file?

Tags: python

I'm writing an addon that switches rigs between FK and IK by reversing and baking constraints.

I have a number of Operators to switch between the different rig types, and they are all using the same bones to run their functions.

I have lists of the same bones that are being used in the scripts, and right now I'm redefining them in each operator, Here's an example of one of the operators:

```
class FK_To_IK(bpy.types.Operator):
"""Tooltip"""
bl_idname = "action.fk_to_ik"
bl_label = "Rig FK To IK"
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

def execute(self, context):
    # region Define variables
    Arm = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
    FKArm = [
    Arm.pose.bones["FK_UpperArm.R"].bone,
    Arm.pose.bones["FK_LowerArm.R"].bone,
    Arm.pose.bones["FK_Hand.R"].bone,
    Arm.pose.bones["FK_Pole.R"].bone,
    ]

    IKArm = [
    Arm.pose.bones["IK_UpperArm.R"].bone,
    Arm.pose.bones["IK_LowerArm.R"].bone,
    Arm.pose.bones["IK_HandControl.R"].bone,
    Arm.pose.bones["IK_Pole.R"].bone,
    ]
    # endregion
```

Since each operator is working on the same bones, I'd like to define the bone lists more globally so I can just call them in each function rather than re-define them.

I've tried to use a separate file vars.py to store them, and I'm trying to call them from another file.

Here's what I'm trying with vars.py:

```
import bpy

class RigGrp(bpy.types.PropertyGroup): #list of rigs that are operated on together. SK FK and IK

    class Rig(bpy.types.PropertyGroup): #list of bones in a rig.
        def __init__(self):
            self.boneList = []
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.SK = RigGrp.Rig()
        self.FK = RigGrp.Rig()
        self.IK = RigGrp.Rig()

class Character(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    Arm = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
   
    #Define R Arm
    Arm_R = RigGrp()

    Arm_R.SK.boneList = [
        Arm.pose.bones["SK_UpperArm.R"].bone,
        Arm.pose.bones["SK_LowerArm.R"].bone,
        Arm.pose.bones["SK_Hand.R"].bone,
    ]

    Arm_R.FK.boneList = [
        Arm.pose.bones["FK_UpperArm.R"].bone,
        Arm.pose.bones["FK_LowerArm.R"].bone,
        Arm.pose.bones["FK_Hand.R"].bone,
        Arm.pose.bones["FK_Pole.R"].bone,
    ]

    Arm_R.IK.boneList = [
        Arm.pose.bones["IK_UpperArm.R"].bone,
        Arm.pose.bones["IK_LowerArm.R"].bone,
        Arm.pose.bones["IK_HandControl.R"].bone,
        Arm.pose.bones["IK_Pole.R"].bone,
    ]

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RigGrp)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Character)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RigGrp)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Character)
```

I'm running into an error when trying to import the vars.py into my init file:

```
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Rig Tools",
    "author" : "Mike Jensen",
    "description" : "",
    "blender" : (3, 0, 0),
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "location" : "",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Rigging"
}

# When bpy is already in local, we know this is not the initial import...
if "bpy" in locals():
    # ...so we need to reload our submodule(s) using importlib
    import importlib
    if "bake_functions" in locals():
        importlib.reload(vars)
        importlib.reload(bake_functions)
        importlib.reload(ui_panel)

from . import vars
from . import bake_functions
from . import ui_panel

import bpy


# =========================================================================
# Registration:
# =========================================================================

def register():
    vars.register()
    bake_functions.register()
    ui_panel.register()

def unregister():
    vars.unregister()
    bake_functions.unregister()
    ui_panel.unregister()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The error I'm running into when Trying to load the addon is:

```
  File "c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\addons\rig_tools\vars.py", line 25, in Character
    Arm = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
AttributeError: '_RestrictData' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Based on what I've been reading in other threads it seems like the way I'm importing vars.py, but I'm not really sure how to address it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot access bpy data when the script is first executed (like you have), or when regsiter is called. You should generally wait until you are called (eg. by an operator being executed) to access bpy. A property group also normally also contains properties, not arbitrary Python globals. I recommend you just have a function which returns whatever you want, and you can call the function when you need it.

Comment: Hey Scurest, I did as you suggested and it was the way to go for me. Thanks for the help!